# Behaviour of as.POSIXct in R with inconsistent daylight saving time data

Tags: r

Can anyone explain this behaviour of as.POSIXct in R.

```
ts <- c("2018-03-24 23:00:00", "2018-03-25 01:00:00", "2018-03-25 01:15:00", 
        "2018-03-25 01:30:00", "2018-03-25 01:45:00", "2018-03-25 02:00:00")

as.POSIXct(ts)
as.POSIXct(ts[1:5])

diff(as.POSIXct(ts))
diff(as.POSIXct(ts[1:5]))
```

The results when running interactive in RStudio are:

```
> as.POSIXct(ts)
[1] "2018-03-24 CET" "2018-03-25 CET" "2018-03-25 CET" "2018-03-25 CET" "2018-03-25 CET" "2018-03-25 CET"
> as.POSIXct(ts[1:5])
[1] "2018-03-24 23:00:00 CET" "2018-03-25 01:00:00 CET" "2018-03-25 01:15:00 CET" "2018-03-25 01:30:00 CET" "2018-03-25 01:45:00 CET"
> 
> diff(as.POSIXct(ts))
Time differences in secs
[1] 86400     0     0     0     0
> diff(as.POSIXct(ts[1:5]))
Time differences in mins
[1] 120  15  15  15
> ts[1:5]
[1] "2018-03-24 23:00:00" "2018-03-25 01:00:00" "2018-03-25 01:15:00" "2018-03-25 01:30:00" "2018-03-25 01:45:00"
> ts
[1] "2018-03-24 23:00:00" "2018-03-25 01:00:00" "2018-03-25 01:15:00" "2018-03-25 01:30:00" "2018-03-25 01:45:00" "2018-03-25 02:00:00"
```

First observation; when looking at all 6 data the 'time' entry disappears. Is this a printout phenomenon only?? 
Second observation, the behaviour of diff seems completely bizarre.

Comment: For your first question, what gets printed to the R console really isn't so important so long as your POSIX ct vector behaves the way it should.  It stores a lot of potential date/time information, which you can access via various functions.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's fine, I buy that, but the behaviour of diff seems to indicate that is not the case, or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem does not lie in the `diff` function. It lies with `as.POSIX*` combined with the DST (Daylight saving time). R does not handle this automatically.

On 25 march, 2018 02:00:00. The CET is set 1 hour foward, changing to CEST time officially. This means 2018-03-25 02:00:00 CET simply does not exist.

Why does this happen?

When calling `as.POSIXct()` some parameters are set as default. One of them is the `tz` (timezone) set at the system's default (mine is CET).

To clarify, I edited your dataset

```
ts <- c("2018-03-25 01:45:00", "2018-03-25 02:00:00", "2018-03-25 03:00:00")
```

Now we run the following line

```
as.POSIXct(ts)
#"2018-03-25 CET" "2018-03-25 CET" "2018-03-25 CET"
```

There is no format parameter given, so R will try different formats, resulting in the timestamps removed. So what if we force a format with timestamps? Running the following line will result in:

```
as.POSIXct(ts, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
# "2018-03-25 01:45:00 CET"  NA    "2018-03-25 03:00:00 CEST"
```

Note that the second value (where a time actually does not exist) is coerced as NA. Because R cannot transform this value to `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"`, it tries an easier format (`"%Y-%m-%d"`). Also note that the third value is in the CEST timezone, passing the DST time. Running the set through a transformation call with a different timezone given, the code succeeds:

```
as.POSIXct(ts[1:3], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC")
#"2018-03-25 01:45:00 UTC" "2018-03-25 02:00:00 UTC" "2018-03-25 03:00:00 UTC"
```

Comment: Ok, I understand! That's a good and detailed explanation! Thanks! I'd better update the question title then, since it had nothing to do with the number of items in the data.

Answer (score 1):

In short answer, there is no "2018-03-25 02:00:00" in CET due to summertime issue.

In detail, `as.POSIXct` function has `tryFormats` parameter, which it applies `format` function to convert from `character` to `POSIXct` class.

Since it is impossible to convert "2018-03-25 02:00:00" to `POSIXct` class, the function uses `%Y-%m-%d` format, not `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS`.

If you tries another timezone, which does not have summer time e.g. `Asia/Seoul`, then you will see they will show datetime format all the time.

```
Sys.setenv(TZ='Asia/Seoul')
as.POSIXct(ts)
> [1] "2018-03-24 23:00:00 KST" "2018-03-25 01:00:00 KST" "2018-03-25 01:15:00 KST" "2018-03-25 01:30:00 KST" "2018-03-25 01:45:00 KST" "2018-03-25 02:00:00 KST"
```